# Node.js server not receiving AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, node.js, browser

I'm using Express and Node.jx 0.6.7.  Server is EC2 Small instance..

For some reason, Node.js is sometimes not receiving my ajax requests (sometimes).  Firebug would say "pending..." and the spinning wheel would show.

It would take about 30 seconds before my node.js server actually gets the request. (When I hit it, I console.log, to check).

I've read information that a browser only allows 6 parallel connections. But, in my Firebug, I never have more than 3!  In fact, I make sure everything loads, and all my ajax requests loads. After I see that everything has loaded, I "click" to call the AJAX...and it hangs. THis is the only spinning loading wheel. Everything else is loaded...so the simultaneous connections cannot be the problem, right?

The server returns responses very fast--the problem is that it's not receiving the response. Literally, the server does not get the request until like 30 seconds later.

This happens with static images just as well. (basically any request. It's really random)

I'm on Firefox 10 and Chrome (latest stable), and this happens.  On Safari, it **never** happens.  It's random and this problem happens in different spots.

Note: this does not happen in my EC2 Micro instance (only on my small instance). They are both the latest versions of Ubuntu.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB7mk.png (as you can see, there is only 1 spinner. Everything else is returned. the Server is NOT under heavy load. it's idle.  Yet, the server is not receiving the request)

Note: I am using AWS Load Balancer, but that's not the problem, because I turned that off and it's still happening.

Comment: If anyone can help, I will offer 500 bounty once this question ends. (even though I can't open it for another 2 days) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

Cloudflare! I disabled the security crap.